# Check if input field contains @

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript, and I am a little confused. How do I check if my input field:

```
<form name='formular' method='post' onsubmit='return atcheck()'>
E-mail <input type='text' name='email' id='em'>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

contains the symbol "@"? I'm not looking for a full good e-mail validation, I just wanna check if the field contains that symbol in particular when submitted (in the atcheck() function).

Comment: [String.prototype.includes](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/includes)

Comment: Btw input type="email" exist too ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `indexOf()` function

[indexOf() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

to get the text on your function, you need to use `document.getElementById("em").value`

Comment: How do I point it to seach my <input id='em'>?

Comment: in your function, get the dom element using getElementById, get the inner text and check it using the function .You could also use RegEx and includes function. There are too many options.

@Downvoter care to explain why the downvote?

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I know php pretty well, but I've never touched JavaScript before. Sorry for the "stupid" question, but I found it difficult to search for something that checks if something contains a certain symbol in a specific place. Most help I found only validates e-mail fully.

Comment: Downvotes are probably only because of my lack of JavaScript knowledge. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="Javascript">
function atcheck(){
    if(document.getElementById('em').value.indexOf('@') === -1) {
        // No @ in string
        return false;
    } else {
        // @ in string
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to accomplish that:

```
function atcheck() {
    var has_at_char = document.getElementById("em").value.indexOf("@") > -1;

    if (has_at_char) {
        return false;
    }

    // your previously exisiting implementation of atcheck() could follow here
}
```

Comment: It's best if you add some commentary and not just toss code out there.